# How should we tag the Dune movies?

Tags: discussion, tags

We now have a third movie for *Dune* (ostensibly a movie series... if they ever get the latter parts made). There are [questions now being asked specific to this movie](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/255230). Normally we'd do [dune-2021](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dune-2021) or such, but this is supposed to be a movie series. Do we want fragmentation into [dune-2021](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dune-2021), [dune-2024](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dune-2024), etc? And do we need separate tags for [questions about the Lynch movie](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/253642/what-did-herbert-think-of-david-lynchs-dune)? What about the SyFy channel mini-series?

Or is it all just [dune](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dune)? Because... *Dune*, 'nuff said.

Comment: How faithful are all the different versions? Normally I'd lean towards series and individual film tags with [[tag:dune]] being the main franchise tag. However, I don't know enough about Dune to know if that's needed or not. If all the versions are pretty faithful then it might not be needed to separate them out.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot From what I know (disclaimer: I've not read the books) all the movies are faithful to the source (Herbert himself seemed pleased with the Lynch movie). The gripes seem to be that most movies have to cut some parts of the novel out for brevity (for comparison, see the two cartoon LOTR movies and compare with the Jackson movies... which [still left some novel material out](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/123991/62709)). Lynch's version opted to [explain large parts of the plot in a single scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AGqdE1NdMTg)

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot to signifcantly varying levels. And the direction was very different. The lynch one was apparently....strange...

Comment: We definitely need the [tag:dune] tag for all questions set in the Dune universe. What we often do in situations like this is to use one universe tag and then either [tag:books] or [tag:movie] for medium-specific questions, but that wouldn't work if there's more than one movie adaptation of the same book. First of all, could someone who knows this universe well (not me) please populate the [tag wiki](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/dune/info) to list all existing books/films/whatever in this franchise? Then at least we'll know what we're working with.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - I've added a non-exhaustive list - https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/dune/info

Comment: 1. [The new one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dune_(novel)#2021_film_by_Denis_Villeneuve). 2. [The old one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dune_(novel)#1984_film_by_David_Lynch) 3. [The one that's talked about quite a lot considering it doesn't exist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jodorowsky%27s_Dune)

Comment: @Valorum you missed the board game ;)

Comment: @SQB - I missed quite a lot of stuff, but until we get a question about the collectible card game, I'm happy with my list

Comment: I think they should be tagged [tag:dune], unless they happen to have a different name than the book(s). That's how most other books turned movies are presently treated. It's up to the poster to clarify which book or movie they are interested in - or if they say nothing, the books/canon is implicitly assumed.

Comment: @Amarth if I want to follow questions about the book, but ignore questions about the films, how do I do that under your suggestion?

Comment: @AncientSwordRage You can't. But to have completely different ways of tagging every work of fiction on a subjective case-to-case basis is utterly confusing. The tag system and core site design is to blame for that I suppose, but it is what it is.

Comment: @Amarth I'm saying we should be consistent and change how we tag stuff to be more sensible and work with the system. We've got a real mess with, for instance, [tag:spider-man-2099] meaning something to [tag:spider-man-2002], and [tag:spider-man-3] using the number in a *third* way. Numbers suck. If I type that last one in, am I supposed to know it's not one of the other third films in either of the other series.

Comment: @Amarth [tag:spider-man-raimi] (to me at least, but I know about spider-man films) is clearer, and lets you add a year or subtitle on afterwards if needed. Also see how planet of the apes, and x-men tags are handled here

Comment: @SQB - which board game? :D there are now several. Of course the classic has been re-released and then re-branded to match the movie but also Dune: Imperium is quite good. A few more as well

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In principle, all our Dune tags should start with `dune` so we can use wildcard searches (I think you can use a leading wildcards, but sticking to one pattern is more consistent)

Then the following token in the tag should either be, presented in order of least ambiguity:

- Books: Title, subtitle, or date (e.g. [dune-1965](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dune-1965): no title, no subtitle, date added to avoid confusion with the franchise tag; [dune-messiah](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dune-messiah): subtitle taken as 'messiah', as using the full title gives [dune-dune-messiah](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dune-dune-messiah) is excessively redundant; or [dune-children-of-dune](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dune-children-of-dune) full title used as there is no sensible subtitle to use, and doesn't introduce excessive redundancy)
- Film: The director, the Production company, or the Distribution company. (e.g. [dune-lynch](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dune-lynch): there is only one Lynch film in the franchise; [dune-villeneuve](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dune-villeneuve): there will be multiple films, however if it's expected there to be one director across the series, we can switch to production company, etc..
- Board/Card/Video Games: Title, Subtitle, Type of game (plus Production company or Year) ( e.g. [dune-card-game](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dune-card-game):  no title, no subtitle and the type of game (card game) is unambiguous enough; [dune-board-game-avalon](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dune-board-game-avalon):  no title, no subtitle and the type of game (boardgame) is ambiguous, so add the production company; [dune-imperium](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dune-imperium): use subtitle; [dune-2000](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dune-2000) use subtitle (2000); [dune-video-game](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dune-video-game) and [dune-video-game-ii](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dune-video-game-ii) )

Finally if needed, the last token should by used to disambiguate between related media:

- [dune-villeneuve-part-one](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dune-villeneuve-part-one) or [dune-villeneuve-2021](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dune-villeneuve-2021)

### Franchise

[dune](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dune) - Only for questions about the franchise as a whole, or media-agnostic questions, and not a meta tag.

Good usage:

- [Where is food found on Arrakis?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/253467/where-is-food-found-on-arrakis) [dune](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dune)[food](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/food) (media-agnostic question)
- [In the original six Dune books, when was the first mention of the Golden path, and did it mean the same thing as it did by the end?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/242218/in-the-original-six-dune-books-when-was-the-first-mention-of-the-golden-path-a) [dune](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dune) (franchise as a whole)

Bad usage:

- [Where is House Ordos in the 2021 movie Dune?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/255230/where-is-house-ordos-in-the-2021-movie-dune) [dune](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dune) (should be [dune-villeneuve-2021](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dune-villeneuve-2021))

#### Books

Should be of the form [franchise-title](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/franchise-title) or [franchise-subtitle](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/franchise-subtitle) or [franchise-year](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/franchise-year)

- [dune-1965](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dune-1965) or [dune-novel](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dune-novel) (should be the *only* one with a date, as there is no subtitle)
- [dune-messiah](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dune-messiah) for the book 'Dune: Messiah' (title already starts with 'dune', so we include subtitle)
- [dune-children-of-dune](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dune-children-of-dune) for the book 'Children of Dune' (title does not start with 'dune', so must prefix with 'dune' if there is space (this introduces redundancy, except where we meet length limitations. Reason being that 'dune-children-of...' should autocomplete 99.99% of the time.)

... and so on

#### Adaptations

- [dune-lynch](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dune-lynch) for use with the 1984 film only (if there had been multiple Lynch films, then we could add a date/subtitle)
- [dune-miniseries-2000](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dune-miniseries-2000) for use with the 2000 syfy miniseries
- [dune-miniseries-2003](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dune-miniseries-2003) for use with the 2003 syfy miniseries
- [dune-villeneuve](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dune-villeneuve) for use with the ongoing film series (only hitch is if we change directors) and not individual films
- [dune-villeneuve-2021](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dune-villeneuve-2021) or [dune-villeneuve-part-one](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dune-villeneuve-part-one) film only tag
- [dune-villeneuve-2023](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dune-villeneuve-2023) or [dune-villeneuve-part-two](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dune-villeneuve-part-two) film only tag

#### Others

Other entries in the [franchise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dune_(disambiguation)#Science_fiction) should follow the scheme outlined above.

Comment: Ideas on how to tag the board/video/card games based on this are welcome to be added

Comment: my head hurts, there may be mistakes in the above

Comment: I don't like identifying them by director and year. It seems like a needlessly complicating factor

Comment: @Valorum I don't see it as any less complicating than using the year it was released. IF you start typing `dune-2` with the other system, you'd get everything released between 2000 and 2999 - and then you need to remember which ones it is. Under this system, typing `dune-v` just gets you the series tag, and the two films. That seems simpler. It also gets you series tags for free.

Comment: If they're still making these in 2998, let's revisit it then.

Comment: Tag-synonyms would let us use both dune-1984 and dune-lynch, but is there then any way to find out which one users are choosing before the services override the selection to the master tag?

Comment: @Jonita but which one is the main and which is the synonym matters.

Comment: Different movie adaptations are typically tagged with a date rather than the director. And the original novel can be simply [tag:dune] the way we know what London is when it's not London, Ontario.

Comment: @Valorum You mean they won't be?

Comment: @spencer the majority of questions tagged [tag:dune] *seem* to be about the franchise or the setting not the book itself. Also I'd totally go for [tag:london-uk] and [tag:london-ca] over your system or valorum's which would be [tag:london-43] and [tag:london-1855], it makes more sense to me.

Comment: I agree with Valorum, the introduction of the director seems needlessly complicating. Do we expect most readers or askers to know who directed a movie? Year seems most sensible, and there's precedent for multi-year anthologies using the year of the first item's release in the tag.

Answer (score 10):

### Franchise

[dune](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dune)

#### Books

- [dune-1965](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dune-1965) or [dune-novel](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dune-novel)
- [dune-messiah](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dune-messiah)
- [children-of-dune](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/children-of-dune)

... and so on

#### Adaptations

- [dune-1984](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dune-1984)
- [dune-2000](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dune-2000)
- [dune-2021](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dune-2021) or [dune-part-one](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dune-part-one)
- [dune-2024](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dune-2024) or [dune-part-two](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dune-part-two)

Comment: My personal preference would be [tag:dune-lynch] for the 1984 film, because that's what people are most likely to remember: who directed it, not when it was released.

Comment: I wasn't aware Lynch had directed it until recently, [when people started comparing the new movie to the old](https://arstechnica.com/gaming/2021/10/before-the-new-version-lets-revisit-1984s-dune-the-greatest-movie-ever-made/) (written by a Lynch fanboy). Only now are people referring to by Lynch's name.

Comment: Dune-1984, Dune-2000, Dune-2021 makes sense to me

Comment: Don't forget the Sci-fi channel mini-series.

Comment: So, Jodorowsky's adaptation would be [tag:dune-∅]?

Comment: This scheme ignores the Sci-Fi channel miniseries (plural), one of which was titled *Children of Dune*. I get using the release year for movies, but how do we handle TV series?

Comment: @Martha even for TV series we use the year when the work started. See [[tag:loki-2021]], for example. The same applies with book series when we use the -year suffix format.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot So, is this answer, its score, and precedent of existing practice enough to get some tags created? I have enough rep to make tag edits, but not enough to create new tags without waiting for them to get approved (and reviewers might miss this Meta thread). As can be seen, we're getting lots of questions about the 2021 movie...

Comment: @SQB we use years to distinguish works with the same name for everything else.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that "part 2" is not also going to be called "Dune", so perhaps wait for its title to be announced before making a decision there.

Comment: Are Dune-Lynch, and Dune-Villeneuve something that can be added as synonyms?

Comment: [tag:Dune-1984], [tag:Dune-2000], [tag:Dune-2021] all neglect to inform whoever is using/viewing the tag *what* the media in question is, i.e. they'd necessarily need to be used with [tag:movie]. It might not be a problem now, but I'm reluctant to set that precedent. For instance, there's a 1984 dune board game, and three video games from 2001. How would *they get* tagged with this scheme?

Comment: also, what would you tag [Dune 2000](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dune_2000) with, [tag:dune-1998]?