Do we really need separate tags for the first and second parts of Villeneuve's "Dune"?
Right now we have dune-2021 and dune-2024 for Dune: Part 1 and Dune: Part 2 respectively.  Since the parts belong together, and aren't standalone works, I don't believe they deserve separate tags.  (Just like we don't create separate tags for each episode of a TV series.)
I think the tag usage for dune-2021 should read something like:

For questions about Denis Villeneuve's "Dune" movie duology released in 2021 (part 1) and 2024 (part 2). Always use in conjunction with the [dune] tag.

dune-2024 should then be removed or merged with dune-2021.

Agreed, making [tag:dune-2024] a synonym of [tag:dune-2021] sounds ideal. It leaves the tag in existence but defaults to the original tag.

Should review some of this Question first. https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13505/how-should-we-tag-the-dune-movies/13511#13511

And also add sort by votes > accepted on Meta.

@Jontia I'd forgotten about that post.  (To be fair, I tend to forget most things more than 3 months back.)  But both answers in that post seem to suggest or accept that Dune: Part 1 and Dune: Part 2 require separate tags, and I think that's simply wrong.

@galacticninja No, because the answers to that question seem to suggest this situation, which I think is incorrect.  It's not really possible to address it there (arguing in comments) so the question stands here.

Year of release seems simplest to me. If you have a question that encompasses both movies, just use both tags?

I'm not sure we should have another discussion post about this, especially since the current top-voted answer (with a score of 9 (+13/-4)) in the original discussion post suggests tagging each movie individually, which seems to reflect a community consensus. Perhaps you could post another answer to that question outlining your disagreement and proposing your alternative tagging approach.

The "consensus" looks a bit weird on that old post. There's an accepted answer from a mod which has a negative score, and then another answer which has a score of 10. What happened there?

"Since the parts belong together, and aren't standalone works" — I mean, they were filmed separately, and released separately.

Yes, as per community consensus and our existing practice of tagging individual movies within a series.
The question of tagging for Villeneuve's Dune films has been raised before on meta: "How should we tag the Dune movies?"

We now have a third movie for Dune (ostensibly a movie series... if they ever get the latter parts made). There are questions now being asked specific to this movie. Normally we'd do dune-2021 or such, but this is supposed to be a movie series. Do we want fragmentation into dune-2021, dune-2024, etc?

While I understand the argument for a single tag encompassing both parts, the current top-voted answer in the original discussion (with a score of 10 [+14/-4]) suggests separate tags for each movie, with either a year identifier or the official movie name (dune-2021 or dune-part-one, dune-2024 or dune-part-two). This approach aligns with our existing practice of tagging individual movies within a series, as seen with the Star Wars and The Lord of the Rings movie series, where each movie has its own tag.
Existing practice is also to add year identifiers to movie tags to avoid confusion with similarly-named works or characters, e.g., questions about the 2012 movie The Avengers are tagged the-avengers-2012, and questions about the 2008 movie The Incredible Hulk are tagged the-incredible-hulk-2008.
This approach makes it easier to find or browse questions specific to a single Dune movie and avoids the confusion of a 2024 film having a "2021" tag. If a question is about both the Villeneuve Dune films, then both dune-2021 and dune-2024 should be used.

My problem with that "consensus" is that it lumps that identification in with a whole lot of other decisions, and it's entirely possible that people felt that most of them made sense and just accepted the answer in general.

@DavidW I tend to agree that past consensus can and should be revisited as needed, but in this particular case I agree with separate tags for each part.

@DavidW Yeah, it's not "consensus ", more "who's shouting the loudest at the time".

@Spencer sadly, I find this to be the case for most Meta "discussions". You have to happen to be online in the time window where this is discussed by a minority of very vocal members who seem to check in daily. Once this minority discussed something, it's "the consensus". That's why I don't think consensus is set in stone; it's just a discussion which was held whenever by a minority of members who happen to be well known because they engage a lot here. In this case however I do happen to agree with that past decision, but I'm all for reviewing it if others disagree!

If "consensus" requires separate tags, we should use meaningful tags (i.e. names) not opaque dates.  The separate parts should be tagged dune-part-one, dune-part-two and eventually dune-part-three and not dune-2021, dune-2024 and dune-2028 (hypothetically).
That this is an appropriate solution is immediately apparent if we start talking about Dune: Part 3, insist on using dune-2027 for it, and then the release date slips a year (or two) making the tag incorrect and requiring a retag.
This also allows the use of the dune-2021 tag to stand for the series as a collective interpretation of the story, if that is useful or necessary.  (This would put dune-1984 and dune-2021 at an equivalent level.)
Note that we have meaningful names for every other sequel ever; we don't have star-wars-1980 or avengers-2015.

"Note that we have meaningful names for every other sequel ever; we don't have star-wars-1980 or avengers-2015" — The tag for 2012's The Avengers, however, is the-avengers-2012, probably to distinguish it from the pre-existing comics, and indeed the unrelated 1998 movie of the same name. The tag for the first Star Wars movie is (a-new-hope)[https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a-new-hope], as it has apparently been eclipsed by the franchise as a whole.

In short: this stuff is messy.

Wouldn't dune-part-one be unclear though? How can you tell it's Villeneuve's Dune from that tag? What if someone else remakes it yet again in 2030 and it's split in two or more parts? (You know another remake is inevitable, given how Hollywood works).

I think [[tag:dune-part-one]] should be made a synonym of [[tag:dune-2021]], and [[tag:dune-part-two]] → [tag:dune-2024]]. Vice versa's fine too, as long as there's one tag for each movie.

Regarding "what if we name the next tag and then the release data slips", the site does not generally accept questions about future works, so by the time any question was on-topic, there would be a definitive release year.

@PaulD.Waite because those sequels don't have the same name as other works
